# why is requestiAnimationFrame so choppy and inconsistent? chrome on ubuntu

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, requestanimationframe

This might be a shot in the dark but I have no idea what's causing this.

I've developed a game engine with webgl. My main testing browser has been firefox and everything works perfectly. No lag or random stutters, even if I'm doing more intense things like blending with multiple framebuffers.

However, on Chrome it's a whole other story. Chrome struggles to keep a stable fps when even running the most simple tasks. I decided to create an experiment to see if the problem was in my code or in the requestAnimation loop. This is the code I ran:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="fpsCounter"></div>

Lowest fps
<div id="minFps"></div>

<br>
Highest fps
<div id="maxFps"></div>
<script>
    var minFps = 999;
    var maxFps = 0

    var fps = 0;
    var last = performance.now();
    var now;
    var fpsUpdateTime = 20;
    var fpsUpdate = 0;
    var fpsCounter = document.getElementById("fpsCounter");
    var minFpsEle = document.getElementById("minFps");
    var maxFpsEle = document.getElementById("maxFps");
    function timestamp(){
        return window.performance && window.performance.now ? window.performance.now() : new Date().getTime();
    }


    var getMaxFps = false;
    setTimeout(function(){
        getMaxFps = true;
    }, 2000);

    function gameLoop(){
        now = performance.now();
        if(fpsUpdate == 0){
            fps = 1000 / (now - last);
            fpsUpdate = fpsUpdateTime;
        }
        fpsUpdate--;

        fpsCounter.innerHTML = fps;
        if(parseInt(fps, 10) < parseInt(minFps, 10)){
            minFps = parseInt(fps, 10);
            minFpsEle.innerHTML = minFps;
        }

        if(parseInt(fps, 10) > parseInt(maxFps, 10) && getMaxFps){
            maxFps = parseInt(fps, 10);
            maxFpsEle.innerHTML = maxFps;
        }

        last = now;
        requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
    }
    gameLoop();
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

All the code does is loop the animation frame and put the fps into a div. On Firefox this works just as well as the whole game engine did, it keeps an average of about 58 and never dipps below 52 fps. Chrome struggles to be above 40 fps and frequently dips below 28. Oddly enough, Chrome has some frequent burst of speed, highest fps chrome got was 99 fps but thats kinda pointless since a stable 60 fps is more important.

Details:

```
Firefox version: 55.0.2 64-bit
Chrome version: 60.0.3112.78 (official version) 64-bit
OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Ram: 8gb
GPU: gtx 960m
Cpu: intel core i7HQ
```

This is how performance looks in Chrome:
[image]

Comment: I'd copied and pasted your code into a html file and running it in chrome, and I'm getting stable ~60 frames; and your code doesn't have any problem since it definitely won't exceed ~10ms execution time limit for RAF; maybe the problem lies in your chrome app itself; what version are you using? try updating your chrome

Answer (score 0):

I made this minimalistic html page for test:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>requestAnimationFrame</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
    <script>
    "use strict"

    // (tested in Ubuntu 18.04 and Chrome 79.0)
    //
    // requestAnimationFrame is not precise
    // often SKIPs a frame
    //

    function loop() {
        requestAnimationFrame(loop)
        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")
        ctx.fillStyle = "red"
        ctx.fillRect(100,100,200,100)
    }

    loop()
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[summary - dev tools image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LkD2.png)

There is no memory leak problem.
The scripting execution time is negligible.

[fps - dev tools image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0f2N.png)

The FPS has inconsistent behaviour (running Chrome on Ubuntu).

In *this test* the problem was hardware acceleration.

The FPS was *ok when hardware acceleration was disabled*.

### EDITED

I have done more tests with a page containing just a single canvas.
My conclusion is that browsers are too much complex (or buggy) and hardly run smoothly 100% of the time.

### my architecture for games

```js
var previousTimeStamp = 0

function mainLoop(timeStamp) {
    if (! shallSkipLoop(timeStamp)) { gameLoop() } 
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop)
}

function gameLoop() {    
    // some code here
}    

function shallSkipLoop(timeStamp) { 
    var deltaTime = timeStamp - previousTimeStamp
    previousTimeStamp = timeStamp
    //
    // avoiding bad frame without less than 1000 / 60 ms!!!
    // this happens when browser executes a frame too late 
    // and tries to be on time for the next screen refresh;
    // but then may start a long sequence of unsynced frames:
    // one very short (like 5ms) the other very long (like 120ms)
    // maybe it is a bug in browser
    //
    return deltaTime < 16
}

requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop)
```